# Como cambiar Texto dentro un DIV sin remplazar el contenido del DIV con Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hola Compañeros estoy tratando de encontrar una manera de cambiar el texto dentro de un DIV este div contiene cajas de texto y botones etc.. lo que quiero es cambiar solo una palabra , ya que al momento de crearse se genera una tabla atraves de una librería y te agrega un paginador y un textbox para buscar dentro de la tabla. pero cuando lo agrega los agrega en ingles y quiero reemplazarlos por su traducción en español. 

 anexo ejemplo:

```html
<div>
<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6"><div class="dataTables_length" id="tbl_sol_length"><label>Show <select name="tbl_sol_length" aria-controls="tbl_sol" class="custom-select custom-select-sm form-control form-control-sm"><option value="10">10</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="50">50</option><option value="100">100</option></select> entries</label></div></div><div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6"><div id="tbl_sol_filter" class="dataTables_filter"><label>Search:<input type="search" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="" aria-controls="tbl_sol"></label></div></div></div>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>HEADER 1</th>
<th>HEADER 2</th>
<th>HEADER 3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>uno</td>
<td>dos</td>
<td>tres</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>cuatro</td>
<td>cinco</td>
<td>seis</td>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Estas usando datatables ?? Si es asi, en Datatables puedes cambiar los valores default a otro idioma mediante la propiedad `language` y ahi le pasas el json con las propiedades que deseas cambiar 
https://datatables.net/plug-ins/i18n/Spanish

Comment: Agrega un elemento <p id='txtNombre> </p> asi solo cambiaras este elemento y no afectas el contenido del div document.getElementById('txtNombre').innerText ='nuevo nombre'

Comment: hola @kiramishima si estoy usando datatables la 1.10.19, me podrias indicar como hacerlo , soy un poco nuevo en esto de usar datatables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como ahora ya se que estas usando Datatables.net , en el codigo javascript del datatable debes usar la propiedad `language`

```
// Ejemplo DT
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tabla_ejemplo').DataTable( {
        "language": {
            "lengthMenu": "Display _MENU_ records per page",
            "zeroRecords": "Nothing found - sorry",
            "info": "Showing page _PAGE_ of _PAGES_",
            "infoEmpty": "No records available",
            "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)"
        }
    } );
} );
```

Dependiendo de que elemento del DT deseas cambiar sera la propiedad que debes agregar al json de idioma, [aqui](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language) puedes encontrar las propiedas que puedes cambiar. Y [aqui](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/i18n/Spanish) la misma comunidad de DT.net ha posteado la traduccion a español, espero sean de ayuda :D

Link Ejemplo: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/language.html